# Change an option string to a function

Tags: php

I'm creating an options page for my theme where I can insert a code in a text field as a condition for displaying sidebars in my website.

Let's say I'm inserting this value in the text input:

```
<input name="condition" value="is_single()">
```

Now I want to use this value as a condition to display the sidebar, something like that:

```
<?php $condition = $options['condition']; if ( $condition ) echo 'sidebar on'; } ?>
```

The problem is $condition in the if statement is considered a string not a function.

I want it to be a function of the value I inserted in the text field.

Comment: This is not wordpress specific question and therefor off-topic here, and should be better asked in SO, but you will need to edit it for that as it is not very clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like that, you would most likely have to use eval() on the text provided ... which **is a really bad idea**.

You would be much better off providing a list of check boxes that have different values so the user can choose which items to show your sidebar on.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="condition[]" value="single" /> Single Post
<input type="checkbox" name="condition[]" value="page" /> Single Page
<input type="checkbox" name="condition[]" value="blog" /> Blog
```

etc.

Personally, I'd highly recommend trying to keep things as simple as possible for users. Maybe have something like the following instead on your theme options:

Show sidebar on blog? -- None -- (drop down box with list of available sidebars)

Show sidebar on single posts? -- None --

Show sidebar on category archives? -- None --

Show sidebar on tag archives? -- None --

What you are trying to do can be made to work ... but consider the average skill of your users and you might find that it is better to give them a list of options to choose for and then reference those options when drawing content.

For example, on your template, you might do the following.

```
$theme_options = get_option('my_theme_options', get_default_theme_options() );
if ( array_key_exists( 'sidebar_positions', $theme_options ) ) {
   if ( is_singular('post') ) {
       if ( array_key_exists( 'singular', $theme_options['sidebar_positions'] ) ) {
           if ( !empty( $theme_options['sidebar_positions']['singular'] ) ) {
               # Draw the specified sidebar
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Anywise, **I strongly recommend against using eval and user input** as that is an easy way to let people accidentally destroy things ... or cause serious problems.

Limit what they can do, give them nice clean options, and then work off of those and your theme will be stronger for it.

(edit)
Since you want to provide real flexibility, you might do one of the following:

**1. Write a meta language for your users.**

For example, you might define a set of commands that are allowed.

Instead of is_single(), have them enter:
    single

Or, for just a particular post:
    single:12

Or, for a few posts:
    single:12,24,25

Or, for their blog:
    blog

If you want multiples chained together, maybe they enter:
    single:12,24,25|blog

Then, you parse the entered value:

```
$entered_value = stripcslashes($_POST['whatever']);
```

And you write a small toolset to properly determine what they entered and what to do with it.

In the above example, your meta language has the following:

- If there is a |, you need to break it into parts on the pipe symbol and you know that each part should be telling you what kind of thing to show on and possibly which specific ones to show on.

You might use explode('|', $entered_value) to grab all of these

- For each piece separated by |, you should have either item_type or item_type:list_of_ids

You can then explode each piece by : (if it is found) to grab the type of item and specific ID values (spliting them by commas and stripping white space) or just store the entire thing (if no : is found).

Once done, you could then build an options array noting where to show the sidebar. For the above example, the final option value might look like:

```
array(
    'single' => array( 12, 24, 25 ),
    'blog' => true
)
```

You could then query your custom options to display your sidebar ... without the nightmare that is eval. You could also check your language logic and report to the user when they made some kind of error.

**An alternative would be to use filters:**

$show_sidebar = apply_filters('sidebar_on_blog', false);

$show_sidebar = apply_filters('sidebar_on_single, false, $post->ID);

The users could then add to their functions file:

```
add_filter('sidebar_on_blog', 'show_my_sidebar_on_blog');
function show_my_sidebar_on_blog($show) {
   return true;
}

add_filter('sidebar_on_single', 'show_my_sidebar_on_single', 10, 2);
function show_my_sidebar_on_single($show, $post_id) {
    $show_on = array(10, 23, 25);
    if ( in_array( $post_id, $show_on ) ) {
       $show = true;
    }
    return $show;
}
```

Of course, then you are wanting your users to program.

If you really must use eval (very bad juju!):

```
try {
    $user_input = $options['condition'];
    $condition = eval("{$user_input}");
    if ( $condition ) {
        echo "sidebar on";
    }
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "<p>Exception Ahoy!</p><pre>" . print_r($e, true) . "</pre>";
}
```

If you need to debug that, you should echo the user input out before running eval to make sure it is a proper statement. In your example, you left out a semi colon ... so if you tell them not to put it in, the eval statement would become:

```
$condition = eval("{$user_input};");
```

You are welcome ... but this is asking for serious problems and support headaches.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. Unfortunately, the checkboxes idea won't help much as I want an extensive options, something like (is_single(11)) or (wp_is_mobile()), I want the admin to enter his desired options. What I'm trying to achieve is the same concept in widget logic plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a meta language then, basically a structure that you can parse _and_ define for your users. You provide a manual on how to input things and then parse them out with strings and process those strings instead of using eval().

Comment: Looks too complicated for me. Could you please guide me how to use eval in this case? I tried `$var = 'is_single()'; if ($eval($var)) echo 'This is true';` but I got `Fatal error: Function name must be a string...`

Comment: I added some comments on alternatives and then added an eval example as well. Please don't take my warnings on eval lightly. Having users enter code to be run is asking for troubles.

Comment: downvoted as the usage of eval will automatically make the theme rejected from the theme repository, and I will not be surprised if themeforest have similar policy. In the wordpress world you don't use eval even for a joke.

Comment: Completely agree. However, he asked how to do it and I very explicitly stated many times that he absolutely should _not_ do it. I don't know his circumstances so I provided an honest answer.

Comment: This plugin already uses eval: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/ And I want to do something similar to it, I'd take the risk, just want to know how to do it.

Comment: Way better to create a quick meta language. Eval should be avoided.

Comment: Ok, an example to use meta language, please?

Comment: See the section labeled Write a meta language for your users. Well worth doing in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I forgot to mention that it's an option for the admin not the end user. That's why there's no risk of eval.

Comment: I got this error with eval: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in...

Comment: That is what we are saying. If you are getting errors with eval, then your users will get lots of them. better to avoid it if possible. Echo out what you are trying to eval and see if it is a proper php command ... but your comment should tell you what you are in for if you use it.

Comment: I got this error from your code. Are you sure your eval synatx is correct?